# How to load models in Realtime from a blend file

Tags: python, game-engine, blend-files

How can I load a model into bge in real time from a blend file with python? In other words when the game is running.

Answer (score 1):

By default the BGE loads everything from a scene at scene start. To add more objects to a scene while the game is running you can use [bge.logic.LibLoad()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bge.logic.html?highlight=libload#bge.logic.LibLoad) to dynamically load all objects from a scene of an external .blend file.

Be aware currently (since 2.78) this is supported:

- loading a single mesh (mesh - not object!)
- loading all objects of a scene
- loading an action

Sample code:

```
def loadAndMergeScene():
    libraryStatus = bge.logic.LibLoad(
        "//Asset.blend",
        "Scene")
    return libraryStatus.libraryName
```

To unload the merged data call LibFree(). The library name should match the one from loading.

```
def removeAndUnloadLibrary(libraryName):
    bge.logic.LibFree(libraryName)
```